# How to use Flatpickr in Stenciljs components?

Tags: css, stenciljs, flatpickr

Flatpickr input field is not showing up in the stencil component with proper css.
I added the flatpickr date input field in a newly created (using stencil cli) app. No other settings or configs are changed.

```
import { Component, h } from '@stencil/core';
import flatpickr from 'flatpickr';


@Component({
  tag: 'my-component',
  styleUrl: 'my-component.css',
  shadow: true,
})
export class MyComponent {

  private element: HTMLInputElement;


  componentDidLoad() {
    
    flatpickr(this.element, {
      
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={el => this.element = el} type="text" id="flatpickr" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is with the styling since the code you posted looks correct.

Flatpickr appends the calendar to the `body` element by default and since CSS is encapsulated when ShadowDOM is enabled (`shadow: true`) the styles in `my-component.css` won't affect it.

I see three options:

**1. Append to different element**

You can set a different parent for the calendar (your component or any element in it)

```
import { Component, Element, h } from '@stencil/core';
// ...
export class MyComponent {
  @Element() el: HTMLElement;

  private element: HTMLInputElement;

  componentDidLoad() {
    flatpickr(this.element, {
      appendTo: this.el,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input ref={el => this.element = el} type="text" id="flatpickr" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And import the styles in the CSS (`my-component.css`):

```css
@import '~flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';
```

**2. Include the Flatpickr CSS globally.**
Include the CSS in your HTML `head` or any global CSS file.

**3. Disable ShadowDOM**
Set `shadow: false` to allow the styles in `my-component.css` to affect elements outside your component and import the CSS in `my-component.css` (same as in Option 1.).